# How to count the comment lines in a java file?

Tags: python

This is part of my code to count the numbers of different lines in a java file. In most cases, this code can get the right number.But if the comment line is like:

/* .......

*.......

*/

it will regard this block as only two lines

```
        for eachLine in allLines:
            if eachLine != " " :
                eachLine = eachLine.replace(" ",""); #remove space
                eachLine = self.trim(eachLine);      #remove tabIndent
                if  (iscomment==False):
                    if(eachLine.strip().startswith("//")): #LINECOMMENT 
                        commentCount += 1;
                    if eachLine == "":
                        blankCount += 1;
                    if(eachLine.strip().startswith("/*")):
                        commentCount += 1;
                        if(not eachLine.strip().endswith("*/")):
                            iscomment=True
                else :
                    commentCount += 1;
                    if(eachLine.find("*/")):
                        iscomment=False
            lineCount = lineCount + 1;
        codeCount=lineCount-commentCount-blankCount
```

Comment: Have a look at [plyj](https://github.com/musiKk/plyj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider [regexp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

comments = re.findall('#.*?\n', allLines)
for item in re.findall('/\*.?*\*/', allLines):
    for row in item.split('\n'):
        comments.append(row)
print(len(comments))
```

Something alone the lines of this, Tried it on a very simple project of mine and it appears to fetch the proper ammount of lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(eachLine.find("*/")):
```

returns -1 on failure, not false.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html